# Simple shadow layer style in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, effects

Using Adobe Illustrator CS3 I usually create a simplest drop shadow by duplicating duplicating the object, moving to background, changing the background color and shifting by few pixels.

This works fine in simplest cases, but the drawback is that I have two copies of this object
which I have to maintain.

How to create such effect and have the objects always up to date?
(e.g. Create text, add a blue copy shifted by few pixels, then when I change the text, I want to have both of the copies at one time).

Answer (score 4):

You can do that with `drop shadow`

**Effect > Stylize > Drop Shadow..**

Just make sure that blur is 0px

[image]

Can be later on controlled from `Appearance window`

**Window > Appearance**

Comment: Looks like this option is not present in CS3.

Comment: @takeshin It is. Took that screenshot from cs3 http://livedocs.adobe.com/en_US/Illustrator/13.0/help.html?content=WS714a382cdf7d304e7e07d0100196cbc5f-61d7.html

Comment: You're right. I looked at Photoshop filters menu, my bad.

Comment: @takeshin :) Well, just in case you are not aware. Same thing does apply in photoshop, though it can be found in `Blending options` http://www.webdesign.org/photoshop/photoshop-basics/blending-options.13410.html

Comment: The shadow is added to the text as expected, but when I update the text, the shadow is not updated.

Comment: @takeshin I can only think that maybe this is a rendering problem.. Try maybe zooming in and out. ( while nothing is selected )

Comment: This is not rendering problem. Drop shadow is added as a separated object, just groupped with the original text.

Comment: @takeshin I'm not even making any sense at this time of the day, lol... Use `Effect > Stylize > Drop Shadow..` and that'll give you what you want.